# Is Visual Studio available for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, visual-studio

I was wondering if Microsoft has Visual Studio available for MAC?

If yes, where can I get it?

Comment: They offer the full IDE Now.

Comment: Got it.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for full fledged Visual Studio IDE for Mac, it is not possible for now. But you may try [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), which is not really there yet. Else, worst case scenario is that you use Bootcamp or Parallels Desktop to have a Windows VM followed by installation of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, Visual Studio is not available on OS X.  Apple offers its own free IDE, however, called Xcode.  You can [download it for free](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/), though you may need to register with the Apple developer network (at no cost).  I'm not much of a fanboy of either Microsoft or Apple, but if you want an IDE for developing for OS X (or iOS) then Xcode would be the most conventional choice.